# Not allow slide from 1% to 100% and vice versa in Circular Slider iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uislider

I'm using this class to create a circular slider but i have a problem,how to not allow when user slide from 1% to 100% and vice versa? Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is code:

```
@interface SLCircularSlider()

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint thumbCenterPoint;

#pragma mark - Init and Setup methods
- (void)setup;

#pragma mark - Thumb management methods
- (BOOL)isPointInThumb:(CGPoint)point;

#pragma mark - Drawing methods
- (CGFloat)sliderRadius;
- (void)drawThumbAtPoint:(CGPoint)sliderButtonCenterPoint inContext:(CGContextRef)context;
- (CGPoint)drawCircularTrack:(float)track atPoint:(CGPoint)point withRadius:(CGFloat)radius inContext:(CGContextRef)context;
- (CGPoint)drawPieTrack:(float)track atPoint:(CGPoint)point withRadius:(CGFloat)radius inContext:(CGContextRef)context;

@end

#pragma mark -
@implementation SLCircularSlider

@synthesize value = _value;
- (void)setValue:(float)value {
    if (value != _value) {
        if (value > self.maximumValue) { value = self.maximumValue; }
        if (value < self.minimumValue) { value = self.minimumValue; }
        _value = value;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        if (self.isContinuous) {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
}
@synthesize minimumValue = _minimumValue;
- (void)setMinimumValue:(float)minimumValue {
    if (minimumValue != _minimumValue) {
        _minimumValue = minimumValue;
        if (self.maximumValue < self.minimumValue)  { self.maximumValue = self.minimumValue; }
        if (self.value < self.minimumValue)         { self.value = self.minimumValue; }
    }
}
@synthesize maximumValue = _maximumValue;
- (void)setMaximumValue:(float)maximumValue {
    if (maximumValue != _maximumValue) {
        _maximumValue = maximumValue;
        if (self.minimumValue > self.maximumValue)  { self.minimumValue = self.maximumValue; }
        if (self.value > self.maximumValue)         { self.value = self.maximumValue; }
    }
}

@synthesize minimumTrackTintColor = _minimumTrackTintColor;
- (void)setMinimumTrackTintColor:(UIColor *)minimumTrackTintColor {
    if (![minimumTrackTintColor isEqual:_minimumTrackTintColor]) {
        _minimumTrackTintColor = minimumTrackTintColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@synthesize maximumTrackTintColor = _maximumTrackTintColor;
- (void)setMaximumTrackTintColor:(UIColor *)maximumTrackTintColor {
    if (![maximumTrackTintColor isEqual:_maximumTrackTintColor]) {
        _maximumTrackTintColor = maximumTrackTintColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@synthesize thumbTintColor = _thumbTintColor;
- (void)setThumbTintColor:(UIColor *)thumbTintColor {
    if (![thumbTintColor isEqual:_thumbTintColor]) {
        _thumbTintColor = thumbTintColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@synthesize continuous = _continuous;

@synthesize sliderStyle = _sliderStyle;
- (void)setSliderStyle:(UICircularSliderStyle)sliderStyle {
    if (sliderStyle != _sliderStyle) {
        _sliderStyle = sliderStyle;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@synthesize thumbCenterPoint = _thumbCenterPoint;

/** @name Init and Setup methods */
#pragma mark - Init and Setup methods
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    } 
    return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup {
    self.value = 0.0;
    self.minimumValue = 0.0;
    self.maximumValue = 1.0;
    /*self.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.thumbTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];*/

    self.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.thumbTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.continuous = YES;
    self.thumbCenterPoint = CGPointZero;

    /**
     * This tapGesture isn't used yet but will allow to jump to a specific location in the circle
     */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureHappened:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureHappened:)];
    panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}

/** @name Drawing methods */
#pragma mark - Drawing methods
#define kLineWidth 5.0
#define kThumbRadius 12.0
- (CGFloat)sliderRadius {
    CGFloat radius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    radius -= MAX(kLineWidth, kThumbRadius);    
    return radius;
}
- (void)drawThumbAtPoint:(CGPoint)sliderButtonCenterPoint inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, sliderButtonCenterPoint.x, sliderButtonCenterPoint.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, sliderButtonCenterPoint.x, sliderButtonCenterPoint.y, kThumbRadius, 0.0, 2*M_PI, NO);

    CGContextFillPath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

- (CGPoint)drawCircularTrack:(float)track atPoint:(CGPoint)center withRadius:(CGFloat)radius inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    float angleFromTrack = translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(track, self.minimumValue, self.maximumValue, 0, 2*M_PI);

    CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + angleFromTrack;
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, NO);

    CGPoint arcEndPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(context);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    return arcEndPoint;
}

- (CGPoint)drawPieTrack:(float)track atPoint:(CGPoint)center withRadius:(CGFloat)radius inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    float angleFromTrack = translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(track, self.minimumValue, self.maximumValue, 0, 2*M_PI);

    CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + angleFromTrack;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, NO);

    CGPoint arcEndPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(context);

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    return arcEndPoint;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint middlePoint;
    middlePoint.x = self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width/2;
    middlePoint.y = self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height/2;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, kLineWidth);

    CGFloat radius = [self sliderRadius];
    switch (self.sliderStyle) {
        case UICircularSliderStylePie:
            [self.maximumTrackTintColor setFill];
            [self drawPieTrack:self.maximumValue atPoint:middlePoint withRadius:radius inContext:context];
            [self.minimumTrackTintColor setStroke];
            [self drawCircularTrack:self.maximumValue atPoint:middlePoint withRadius:radius inContext:context];
            [self.minimumTrackTintColor setFill];
            self.thumbCenterPoint = [self drawPieTrack:self.value atPoint:middlePoint withRadius:radius inContext:context];
            break;
        case UICircularSliderStyleCircle:
        default:
            [self.maximumTrackTintColor setStroke];
            [self drawCircularTrack:self.maximumValue atPoint:middlePoint withRadius:radius inContext:context];
            [self.minimumTrackTintColor setStroke];
            self.thumbCenterPoint = [self drawCircularTrack:self.value atPoint:middlePoint withRadius:radius inContext:context];
            break;
    }

    [self.thumbTintColor setFill];
    [self drawThumbAtPoint:self.thumbCenterPoint inContext:context];
}

/** @name Thumb management methods */
#pragma mark - Thumb management methods
- (BOOL)isPointInThumb:(CGPoint)point {
    CGRect thumbTouchRect = CGRectMake(self.thumbCenterPoint.x - kThumbRadius, self.thumbCenterPoint.y - kThumbRadius, kThumbRadius*2, kThumbRadius*2);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(thumbTouchRect, point);
}

/** @name UIGestureRecognizer management methods */
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizer management methods
- (void)panGestureHappened:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
   /* UILabel* percentlbl =(UILabel*) [self.superview viewWithTag:10];
    NSLog(@"percentlbl frame %f",percentlbl.frame.origin.y
          );
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(percentlbl.frame, tapLocation)) {
        NSLog(@"Tapped label");
    }*/


    switch (panGestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGFloat radius = [self sliderRadius];
            CGPoint sliderCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
            CGPoint sliderStartPoint = CGPointMake(sliderCenter.x, sliderCenter.y - radius);
            CGFloat angle = angleBetweenThreePoints(sliderCenter, sliderStartPoint, tapLocation);

            if (angle < 0) {
                angle = -angle;
            }
            else {
                angle = 2*M_PI - angle;
            }

            self.value = translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(angle, 0, 2*M_PI, self.minimumValue, self.maximumValue);
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            if (!self.isContinuous) {
                [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            }
            if ([self isPointInThumb:tapLocation]) {
                [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            else {
                [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)tapGestureHappened:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
    if (tapGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint tapLocation = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
        if ([self isPointInThumb:tapLocation]) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}

/** @name Touches Methods */
#pragma mark - Touches Methods
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    if ([self isPointInThumb:touchLocation]) {
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }
}

@end

/** @name Utility Functions */
#pragma mark - Utility Functions
float translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(float sourceValue, float sourceIntervalMinimum, float sourceIntervalMaximum, float destinationIntervalMinimum, float destinationIntervalMaximum) {
    float a, b, destinationValue;

    a = (destinationIntervalMaximum - destinationIntervalMinimum) / (sourceIntervalMaximum - sourceIntervalMinimum);
    b = destinationIntervalMaximum - a*sourceIntervalMaximum;

    destinationValue = a*sourceValue + b;

    return destinationValue;
}

CGFloat angleBetweenThreePoints(CGPoint centerPoint, CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2) {
    CGPoint v1 = CGPointMake(p1.x - centerPoint.x, p1.y - centerPoint.y);
    CGPoint v2 = CGPointMake(p2.x - centerPoint.x, p2.y - centerPoint.y);

    CGFloat angle = atan2f(v2.x*v1.y - v1.x*v2.y, v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y);

    return angle;
}
```

Comment: That is a strange use of `@synthesize`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a stage in your gesture recognition where you determine if the user is increasing or decreasing the counter. If decreasing, do not respond to decrease changes once the value drops below zero (probable you want to be able to get to zero, not stop at one despite what the question says?). If increasing, don't respond to increase changes once value gets to 100%. You need to ensure of course that while at the maximum you continue to be responsive if the user changes to decrease the value, and likewise to increasing when at zero.